# Image upload preview in a java panel

Tags: java, swing

Am creating a user interface in java.The panel is for helping the client to select an image.
It has a text box for path and a browse button to search for files. Once the client has chosen a file, the preview must show the image.

Comment: And the question is ...?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [`JFileChooser` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html), you will find [an example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#advancedexample) on a file chooser with a preview area for images. Is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 2):

> *..chosen a file...*

If you want to show the preview after selecting the file,

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Now add it to a frame or panel or anything like you usually do!